# Cannot use `ember-power-select` in {{#each}} block

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

```
//controller
categories: ['category0', 'category1', 'category2'],
units: ['unit0', 'unit1', 'unit3'],

//hbs
<ul>
  {{#each categories as |category|}}
    <label>{{category}}</label>
    <li>
      <label>Select Unit</label>
      {{#power-select
        options=units
        selected=selected
        onchange=(action (mut selected)) 
        as |unit|
      }}
        {{unit}}
      {{/power-select}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

The above code generated 3 power-select boxes. When I select a value in the 1st power-select box, the same value gets selected in the 2nd and 3rd box too.

There are 3 categories so it loads three power-select boxes. All 3 power-select options are of same array (units: ['unit0', 'unit1', 'unit3']).

What is the way to make each power-select box unique one? So that i can select a different value in each power-select boxes.

Comment: Problem is, how are you going to maintain selectedUnit for each power select, currently you are providing `unit` as `selected` but that's scope to the particular each block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The below solution works

```
categories: [{label: 'category0'}, {label: 'category1'}, {label: 'category2'}
],
units: ['unit0', 'unit1', 'unit3']

<ul>
  {{#each categories as |category|}}
    <label>{{category}}</label>
    <li>
      <label>Select Unit</label>
      {{#power-select
        options=units
        selected=category.selected
        onchange=(action (mut category.selected)) 
        as |unit|
      }}
        {{unit}}
      {{/power-select}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

[working twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/f7b687fd43a9b72fd21b6ab720647965?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C)

Answer (score 0):

You need to send selectedItem property to ember-power-select, currently you are sending the each block scope `unit` property.

I modified your code to include `selected`

```
Units: [{name:'Unit0',selected:''},{name:'Unit1',selected:''},{name:'Unit2',selected:''}]
```

and in hbs,

```
<ul>
  {{#each Units as |unit|}}
    <li>
      <label>Select Unit</label>
      {{#power-select
        selected=unit.selected
        options=Units 
        onchange=(action (mut unit.selected)) 
        as |unit|
      }}
        {{unit.name}}
      {{/power-select}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Here is the [working twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/121b22af3062cc04d55791534bd110dd?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)

Comment: I edited my question. Please have a look at it.
"There are 3 categories so it loads three power-select boxes. All 3 power-select options are of same array (units: ['unit0', 'unit1', 'unit3'])"

Comment: Convert categories array to hold selectedItem for each category like I did it in `Units`

Comment: i modified the above code and it works. 
"selected=category.selected
  onchange=(action (mut category.selected))"

Comment: @rinold I was on the phone not able to update the answer to your updated question, so you can write your answer and mark it as an accepted answer, that will be super helpful to others.